# How does javascript, jquery work in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, symfony

I am trying to understand how do you use jquery or other scripts in Symfony2. I read the Assets documentation, however that didnt help me that much.

So I have a base.html.twig file in which I add the jquery library and my script file that contains a simple script.

I add it like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {# Le Javascript #}         
    {% javascripts 
        'bundles/mpFrontend/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'         
        'Mp/ShopBundle/Resources/js/scripts.js'   
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>       
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

Now I have a index.html.twig in which I extend the base.html.twig.... Is that all I need? For me the script doesn’t work, do I need to somehow access it in index.html.twig too?

Comment: are the file loaded by the browser? if not, check in the web folder if the path are correct, if it is not present launch the command `assets:install`. Hope this help.

Comment: Symfony is backend, JavaScript frontend. JS works just like it did with another backend.

Comment: @Matteo I cant access the code right now but im pretty sure the paths are correct, and i did the assets install too. So I dont need to do anything in index.html.twig to access the script? It works automatically if i extend the base.html.twig?

Comment: of course you are using assetic so you must dump the content with the correct CLI command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messed up with Asstic library and Assets commponent. It is not the same. You should use command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

This command will compile your js file and will put it in right place.

Comment: I cant access the code right now, but is assetic:dump the only thing I need to do?